# Float with overflow scroll in css

Tags: html, css

how to set overflow-x scroll with float left,if set float left to sub div, can't scroll because sub div set within screen.and can't set width to parent div because sub div are dynamic.

```css
.parent div{
    overflow-x:scroll;
    display:Block;
}
.sub div{
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: please paste your code

Comment: .parent div{
    overflow-x:scroll;
    display:Block;
}
.sub div{
    float:left;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Try to

```css
.parent {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  display: Block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.parent .sub {
  /*float:left;*/
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="sub">testing</div>
  <div class="sub">testing testing</div>
  <div class="sub">testing</div>
  <div class="sub">testing testing</div>
  <div class="sub">testing</div>
  <div class="sub">testing</div>
  <div class="sub">testing</div>
  <div class="sub">testing</div>
  <div class="sub">testing</div>
  <div class="sub">testing</div>
  <div class="sub">testing</div>
  <div class="sub">testing testing</div>
  <div class="sub">testing</div>
  <div class="sub">testing</div>
  <div class="sub">testing</div>
  <div class="sub">testing</div>
  <div class="sub">testing</div>
  <div class="sub">testing</div>
</div>
```